# How to get the value of a Resource from it's string name

Tags: c#, localization, resource-files

I have been using resource files and referencing them in my views in the standard way for example `Resources.Labels.CountryName`.  But I have a situation where I need to get the value of the resource in my C# from the resource name as a string i.e.

```
string resourceName = "Resource.Labels.CountryName";
```

How would I get the value in the resource file from this string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you get resources with

```
GetLocalResourceObject("~/VirtualPath", "ResourceKey");
GetGlobalResourceObject("ClassName", "ResourceKey");
```

You may adapt this. I write my own extensions for the HTML helper like this one for global resources:

```
public static string GetGlobalResource(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string classKey, string resourceKey)
{
    var resource = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(classKey, resourceKey);
    return resource != null ? resource.ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

I think, in your example with this you would get the resource in your view with `@Html.GetGlobalResource("Labels", "CountryName")`.

Because local resources need the virtual path and I don't want to write it into the view, I use this combination, which gives both opportunities:

```
public static string GetLocalResource(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string virtualPath, string resourceKey)
{
    var resource = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(virtualPath, resourceKey);
    return resource != null ? resource.ToString() : string.Empty;
}

public static string Resource(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string resourceKey)
{
    var virtualPath = ((WebViewPage) htmlHelper.ViewDataContainer).VirtualPath;
    return GetLocalResource(htmlHelper, virtualPath, resourceKey);
}
```

With that you can get a local resource very comfortable by writing `@Html.Resource("Key")` in your view. Or use the first method to get local resources of other views like with `@Html.GetLocalResource("~/Views/Home/AnotherView.cshtml", "Key")`.

Comment: Comprehensive answer, thanks...had a little trouble with this as I didn't have my resource files in App_GlobalResources but instead in Content/Resources, but have managed to get it working now.